# Why can't I store boost::function in std::list?

Tags: c++, list, boost

I get the following compilation error:

```
error: expected `;' before 'it'"
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <list>

template< class T >
void example() {
    std::list< boost::function<T ()> >::iterator it;
}
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to put `typename` in front of that line, since the type you do ::iterator upon is dependant on the template-parameter T. Like this:

```
template< class T >
void example() {
    typename std::list< boost::function<T ()> >::iterator it;
}
```

Consider the line

```
std::list< boost::function<T ()> >::iterator * it;
```

which could mean a multiplication, or a pointer. That's why you need `typename` to make your intention clear. Without it, the compiler assumes not a type, and thus it requires an operator there or a semicolon syntactically.

---

Also consult the new C++ FAQ entry [Where to put template and typename on dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names).