# Template class with "typename"

Tags: c++

I have a template class where I want to use objects of that class (along with the parameterized type) inside a map. So far this is the solution that I've been able to arrive at:

```
class IStatMsg;

template <typename T>
class ITier
{
public:

    // Methods
    ITier(TierType oType) : o_Type(oType){};
    virtual ~ITier(){};

    typename ITier<T> ParamITier;  // line 60

    ITier* Get(T oKey)
    {
        std::map<T, ParamITier*>::iterator it = map_Tiers.find(oKey);   // line 64

        if (it != map_Tiers.end())
            return it->second;

        return NULL;
    }

    void Set(T oKey, ITier* pTier)
    {
        map_Tiers.insert(pair<T, ParamITier*>(oKey, pTier)); // line 74
    }

    TierType GetType() { return o_Type; }

protected:
    // Methods

    // Attributes
    std::map<T, ParamITier*> map_Tiers;  // line 83
    TierType o_Type;

private:
    // Methods

    // Attributes
};
```

But when I try to compile this code I get a long list of errors:

> /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:60:
>   error: expected nested-name-specifier
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:60:
>   error: `ITier<T>' specified as
>   declarator-id
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:60:
>   error:   perhaps you want`ITier'
>   for a constructor
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:60:
>   error: two or more data types in
>   declaration of `ITier<T>'
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:60:
>   error: expected`;' before
>   "ParamITier"
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:83:
>   error: `ParamITier' was not declared
>   in this scope
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:83:
>   error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:83:
>   error: template argument 4 is invalid
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:83:
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of`
>   map_Tiers' with no type
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:
>   In member function `ITier<T>*
>   ITier<T>::Get(T)':
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:64:
>   error:`ParamITier' undeclared (first
>   use this function)
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:64:
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is
>   reported only once for each function
>   it appears in.)
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:64:
>   error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:64:
>   error: template argument 4 is invalid
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:64:
>   error: expected `;' before '::' token
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:66:
>   error:`it' undeclared (first use this
>   function)
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:66:
>   error: request for member `end' in`
>   ((ITier*)this)->ITier::map_Tiers',
>   which is of non-class type `int'
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:
>   In member function`void
>   ITier::Set(T, ITier*)':
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:74:
>   error: request for member `insert' in`
>   ((ITier*)this)->ITier::map_Tiers',
>   which is of non-class type `int'
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:74:
>   error:`pair' undeclared (first use
>   this function)
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:74:
>   error: expected primary-expression
>   before ',' token
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:74:
>   error: `ParamITier' undeclared (first
>   use this function)
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:74:
>   error: expected primary-expression
>   before '>' token
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:
>   At global scope:
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:93:
>   error: base`ITier' with
>   only non-default constructor in class
>   without a constructor
>   /home/gayanm/street/src/QueryServer_NEW/ITier.h:109:
>   error: expected class-name before '{'
>   token

Could you please point out how to fix these?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 60 does not access a depending name. What you use is `ITier<T>` of which the compiler knows it's a template given an argument. Instead of `typename` you want to use `typedef` ;)

Line 64 *does* access the depending name `iterator` which is a type-name, so you have to put `typename` before `std::map`. I put the two disambiguations, *template* and *typename* on this answer: [Disambiguations of dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389797/gcc-template-issue#390201).

Line 74 would be right, if you fix the bug in Line 60, as far as i can see.

Line 83 is alright in itself as far as i can see.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would recommend that you pass `const T&` to the functions instead of `T`, since you cannot be sure (it's a template parameter!) that it'll be a "cheap" copy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot litb. I was able to fix my code with the guidelines you provided.

```
class IStatMsg;

template <typename T>
class ITier
{
public:

    // Methods
    ITier(){};
    ITier(TierType oType) : o_Type(oType){};
    virtual ~ITier(){};

    //typename ITier<T> ParamITier; 

    ITier<T>* Get(T oKey)
    {
        typename std::map<T, ITier<T>*>::iterator it = map_Tiers.find(oKey);    

        if (it != map_Tiers.end())
            return it->second;

        return NULL;
    }

    void Set(T oKey, ITier<T>* pTier)
    {
        map_Tiers.insert(std::pair<T, ITier<T>*>(oKey, pTier));
    }

    TierType GetType() { return o_Type; }

protected:
    // Methods

    // Attributes
    std::map<T, ITier<T>*> map_Tiers;
    TierType o_Type;

private:
    // Methods

    // Attributes
};
```

Comment: you dont need to use  ITier<T> . ITier suffices. It's a so-called injected name that refers to the class you are in.